# Wordpress Cron job hook running multiple times

Tags: wp-cron

Here is my code in its basic form for a wp cron job I want to run only once daily:

```php
add_filter('cron_schedules', function ($schedules) {
    $schedules['daily_reminder_check'] = array(
        'interval' => 86400,
        'display' => __('Once Daily'),
    );
    return $schedules;
});

if (!wp_next_scheduled('daily_reminder_check')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily_reminder_check', 'send_collection_reminders');
}

add_action('send_collection_reminders', function () {
    wp_mail('test@example.com', 'reminder', 'here it is');
});
```

I have have my constant for disabling cron to tru:

```php
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );
```

so that I can use my hosting to run the cron from wget from:

https://example.com/wp-cron.php

But when that happens the `send_collection_reminders` hook is run multiple times. which means my users would receive multiple reminder emails.

I just need it run once when I call the cron.

Can anyone help?

##### UPDATE

The only difference to the full code is the `send_collection_reminders` hook. BTW There is only 1 entry in the foreach loop.

```php
add_action('send_collection_reminders', function () {
    if ($collections = get_field('collections', 'options')) {
        foreach ($collections as $collection) {
            if($collection['reminders'] != false) {
                wp_mail($collection['email_address'], 'daily reminder', 'here it is');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: do you have more than one server e.g. a load balancing system or distributed machines/lambdas? Also where is this code located? And how does your manual cron triggering work? You mentioned `wget` and `wp-cron.php` but there's no code or details of how that happens

Comment: No load balancing or distribution like that. Just a cPanel cron job that runs everyday at 6am by performing a wget on the wp-cron.php url of the site. The above code is located in my functions.php if that helps.

Comment: can you share the specifics? Even a screenshot if not a copy paste of the crontab would be helpful. I'm also assuming the define you shared is in your `wp-config.php`, and it's above the include for the wp settings php file? Also if your cron is only triggered once a day at 6am then would that not cause issues with all the other cron jobs from plugins, transient cleanup, published posts etc that run more often?

Comment: yeah, the define is in the wp-config in the correct place. When the define was not in place, at 6am the code above sent out 6 emails instead of just one. When the define is set to false it only sends 3 emails, but again it should only send one.

Comment: as for plugins, transient cleanup, published posts etc... a daily run of the wp crons is sufficient for this particular website. All content is behind login protection and is more functionality-based and is only in WP for its data structure really

Comment: futher to the specifics... If I went to the wp-cron.php URL in the browser at any time it fires the hook but I would expect it to only run if it has been a day (or more) since it was last run/scheduled

Comment: what about the location of the code or the additional info about how the cron is triggered? There are a lot of ways to trigger a cron with `wget`. Do you have plugins that impact email such as SMTP? Have you directly experienced this problem yourself or is this something you're debugging remotely from user reports? Also there is nothing in the code that retrieves user emails, there's a very high chance the bug has been removed in an effort to make the code more generic/abstract to hide things and simplify the question. It may be that 1 cron job happens, but the code fires multiple emails